# XAMPP Linux: make mysql accessible by just typing "mysql"

Tags: mysql, linux, xampp

I have a strange issue. On my PC with Linux Mint 17 I can access mysql just by typing `mysql` in the terminal, but on my laptop (with Ubuntu 15.04) I have to type each time `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql` (both have the latest XAMPP version installed).

So my question is: how to make mysql "global" and accessible by just typing "mysql"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `/opt/lampp/bin/` to your `$PATH` so that the system can find the binary file.

From the command line enter:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 for doublesharp's answer.  Otherwise, you could do:

```
alias mysql=/opt/lampp/bin/mysql
```

This avoids making everything in `/opt/lampp/bin/` immediately accessible on the path, which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @doublesharp, enter this line into the file .bashrc in your home directory

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```